# exwings range.value returns list in list

Tags: python, excel, range, xlwings

The task is very simple - I need to check the amount of rows which having data, get these rows in the list and use cycle to insert every element in BD.

But the problem is in the line  `data = sheet.range(f"A8:G{last_row}").value`, if range is more than 1 row it returns **list in list** and folowing cycle goes on every list in list and works perfect, but if range contains only 1 raw, it returns just list with values and the following cycle goes on these values and returns some symbols or smth else, but not the values of element of list in list.

How to make it list in list if there is only 1 raw in a source ?

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings import Range, constants
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

cur_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000')
wb = xw.books.open('CF.xlsm')
sheet = wb.sheets('Inserter')

last_row = sheet.range('A' + str(sheet.cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row
data = sheet.range(f"A8:G{last_row}").value  

print(type(data))

 def check_none(x): 
     x = '' if x is None else x
     return x


 try:
     connection = psycopg2.connect(
         host='',
         database='',
         user='',
         password=''
     )
     connection.autocommit = True
     for i in data:
         id = i[0]
         level1 = check_none(i[1])
         level2 = check_none(i[2])
         level3 = check_none(i[3])
         level4 = check_none(i[4])
         amount = check_none(i[5])
         comment = check_none(i[6])

         with connection.cursor() as cursor:
             cursor.execute(f'''
                 insert into xxxxxx.xxxxxxx (ID, level_1, level_2, level_3, level_4, date, date_eom, amount, comment)
                 values (
                 '{id}',
                 '{level1}',
                 '{level2}',
                 '{level3}',
                 '{level4}',
                 '{cur_time}',
                 (date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date,
                 {amount},
                 '{comment}')
                 ''')

             print("[INFO] Data was succefully inserted")


 except Exception as _ex:
     print("[INFO] Error while working with PostgreSQL", _ex)
 finally:
     if connection:
         # cursor.close()
         connection.close()
         print("[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed")
```

Answer (score 1):

To always return a nested list, you can set the `ndim=2` option:

```py
data = sheet.range(f"A8:G{last_row}").options(ndim=2).value
```

See also the respective part in the docs: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/datastructures.html#lists